# Dynamic link to download my app from iOS Android app stores

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

With firebase, how can I generate a download link of my app and when click on it, redirects to the Apple store if the user has iOS and google play if he has Android??? Can I also have the data of how many users download the app through this link?

Thank you so much

I tried to search in the firebase documentation, i read the documentation of how to create dynamic link but i can't figure out how to do it.